# Simple background changes not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to understand why these 2 functions aren't working correctly. I just want it so that clicking button 1 changes the background style to colour blue, and button 2 changing the class name. But I want to do it the ways demonstrated in the fiddle.

Can someone explain why these aren't working? I was at my new job today and want to learn why it did not work as I believe it's a simple fix with possible syntax errors. thanks for any explanation

```js
var el = document.getElementByClassName('test');

function taskOne() {
  alert('task 1 executed successfully');
  el.style.background="blue !important";
}

function taskTwo() {
  alert('task 2 executed successfully');
  el.className += " test-2";
}
```

```css
.test {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.test-2 {
  background: orange !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">content</div>
<div class="test">content 2</div>
<div class="test">content 3</div>
<div class="test">content 4</div>
<div class="test">conten4t 5</div>

<button onClick="taskOne()">Task 1</button>

<button onClick="taskTwo()">Task 2</button>
```

Comment: getElementByClassName('classname') does not exist

Comment: the correct method is getElementsByClassName() https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Comment: I also highly recommend, if you plan to manipulate collections of elements in this way, you use jQuery to do it, otherwise you will be iterating over the array of elements yourself as Lwin Htoo Ko shows. Unless you like typing a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClassName`. It returns array of elements with that class name.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('test');

function taskOne() {
  for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    let el = elements[i];
    el.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
}

function taskTwo() {
  for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    let el = elements[i];
    el.className += " test-2";
  }
}
```

```css
.test {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.test-2 {
  background: orange !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">content</div>
<div class="test">content 2</div>
<div class="test">content 3</div>
<div class="test">content 4</div>
<div class="test">content 5</div>

<button onClick="taskOne()">Task 1</button>

<button onClick="taskTwo()">Task 2</button>
```

Comment: thank you - good explanation which will help me very much in the future!

Answer (score 2):

getElementByClassName(), singular, doesn't exist. Instead, try to use getElement**s**ByClassName(). You must be aware that it returns not an element, but an array of elements.

Answer (score 1):

> var el = document.getElementByClassName('test');

The correct method name is `getElementsByClassName`, hence the TypeError you were getting.

Also keep in mind that the method returns an array of elements that have that class name. This means that you will want to loop through each of them (if any) with a `for` if you want to set all of their background colours (the correct property is `el.style.backgroundColor`, as opposed to the one that you have used: `el.style.background`) to say `red`.